# Loop does not read first word as it does the others in a string

Tags: python, string, loops, replace, cpu-word

The goal of this is to censor the first string input, which will be a sentence, where the second string is a word to be censored. Given an input of `censor("hey hey hey", "hey")`, the result is `"hey *** ***"`. I can't figure out why the first `hey` should be different from the other so that it doesn't get replaced. Any ideas?

```
def censor(text, word):
    text_list = []
    word_replace = []
    for char in word:
        word_replace.append('*')
    replace = ''.join(word_replace)
    for char in text:
    text_list = text.split()
    for key in text_list:
        str(key)
        if key == word:
            text_list.append(replace)
            text_list.remove(key)
    final = ' '.join(text_list)
    return final
```

Comment: Why not a simple comprehension? The body of the function should only have 1 or 2 lines with the last 1 starting with return ' '.join(

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in text_list:
    #...
    text_list.append(replace)
    text_list.remove(key)
```

Here you are trying to modify `text_list` while iterating over it. Don't do that. The simple fix is to iterate over its copy:

```
for key in text_list[:]:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a lot of appends in a loop in Python it is a good sign that you should be using list comprehension or a generator expression instead.

It is also a very bad idea to be removing items from an array or list while iterating over it.

```
def censor(text, word):
    replacement_word = "*" * len(word)
    return " ".join(replacement_word if key == word else key for key in text.split())
```

Also please note that the best way to do this kind of thing is to use the builtin [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method. Or even [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) if you need more control.

Comment: Agreed.  Using str.replace() is ideal here.  It becomes a one liner:

```def replace(phrase, word):
       return phrase.replace(word, "*" * len(word))```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be made cleaner in a couple of ways. For one thing -- the * operator on strings is useful:

```
>>> 'hello' * 3
'hellohellohello'
>>>
>>> '*' * 3
'***'
```

You could perhaps use this to write a helper function that censors individual words. Something like:

```
def censorWord(candidate, word):
    if candidate == word:
        return '*' * len(word)
    else:
        return candidate
```

Typical output:

```
>>> censorWord("hey","hey")
'***'
>>> censorWord("hi", "hey")
'hi'
```

Also, in your code I would recommend constructing an entirely new list (say called censored_words) rather than trying to modify the given list. That way you can just append censored words constructed by repeatedly applying the censorWord function to the words in text_list and not worry about removing anything.

As you go deeper in Python you'll eventually be able to write functions like this in just a couple of lines (as in Samuel O'Malley's excellent answer), but it isn't a bad exercise to be able to first build up lists in a cleaner fashion.